# Shell script to Get a value

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to make a shell script, which will read number of lines (Like below) and only print "Queries per second avg: VALUE" string.

Threads: 1 Questions: 2459965658 Slow queries: 400 Opens: 103532 Flush tables: 165 Open tables: 64 Queries per second avg: 726.243

How can i realize this using shell script.?

Comment: Do you want a bash-only solution or are standard tools okay?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? It really motivates answerers if you show the efforts you have made.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is the traditional tool for a job like this

```
sed -e 's/.* Queries/Queries/' your_file
```

Recent versions of bash, however, support regex natively.

```
while read -r line ; do
    [[ $line =~ avg:\ .* ]] && echo Queries per second ${BASH_REMATCH[*]}
done < your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

sed

```
sed -r 's/^.*(Queries.*)$/\1/'
```

bash

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    echo "Queries${line##*Queries}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
... | grep -o 'Queries per second avg: [0-9.]\+'
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I have tried all the above solutions and found this solution is suitable for my problem. My Solutions is now "mysql -uroot -pPASSWORD -Bse '\s' | grep -o 'Queries per second avg: [0-9.]\+'"